# Resolving a sub-URI relative to a base URI

Tags: java, uri

If we have:

```
URI base = new URI("foo/bar");
URI sub = new URI("baz");
```

How can we get the sub-URI relative to the base URI (i.e. "foo/bar/baz")?

The following doesn't work (produces "foo/baz"):

```
base.resolve(sub);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your base URI should end with a slash : `new URI("foo/bar/");`

If URI does not end with slash, everything after last slash will be cut.

[Specification](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt), if you're mad enough, or just check the `URI#resolve` code.